# Pasar valor de outputText a javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

He usado lo siguiente pero no funciona

```html
 <h:outputText id="text" value="#{managebBean.informacion.text}"/>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 var myObject= document.getElementById("text").value;

</script>
```

Pero sale un error, de que "value" es null

Answer (score 0):

intenta esto:
en la etiqueta script solo deja el atributo type
según veo jsf genera un su propio id y h:outputText genera un span.

Tal ves esto funcione reemplaza tu script por la siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    var myObject = "";
    for(elem of elements){
       e = elem.getAttribute("id");
       if(e.includes("text")) myObject = elem.value;
    }
</script>
```